# Android - Share ToolBar across whole application

Tags: java, android

I have 3 ToolBars that I use across my whole application

The first one is just a ToolBar with a close button.

The second one is a ToolBar with a close and delete icon.

The third one is a ToolBar with a close and home icon.

Here is my case, I use this ToolBar in many places, and I dont want to use Fragment for some reasons so I am forced to use Activity.

For usability, I created methods to handle their functions, but I am sure I can do something to make this easier as I repeat this code in each activity.

**toolbar_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/CloseImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_48dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ToolBar Title"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**toolbar_layout_delete_icon.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/CloseImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_48dp"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ToolBar Title"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/CloseImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.54" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/DeleteImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_icon_36dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**toolbar_layout_home_icon.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/CloseImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_48dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ToolBar Title"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_white_36dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/HomeImageView" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

java method that handles the ToolBar :

```
private void setupToolbar() {
        Toolbar mytoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
        TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) mytoolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitle);
        toolbarTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.submit_claim));
        ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) mytoolbar.findViewById(R.id.CloseImageView);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(v -> finish());
        ImageView HomeButton = (ImageView) mytoolbar.findViewById(R.id.HomeImageView);
        HomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(PolicyAndContactDetailActivity.this , MainActivity.class);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(mIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

I need to minimize my code as much as possible, and any help with @+id names will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Base Activity with ToolBar` and let all your activity extend the BaseActivity like below code I've given :

**BaseActivity**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

**Main.xml (Base activity layout)**

> ```
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>         android:theme="@style/toolbarTheme"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="@color/green"
>         android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
> ```

Now every Activity extends BaseActivity instead of AppCompatActivity or ActionBarActivity so you can get access to the Toolbar in every Activity.

Your **MainActivity**

> ```
> public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity{ //your code }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use include Tag in your activity layouts and toolbar method in separate class to reuse in all activities. 
change your method signature:-

`private void setupToolbar(View.OnClickListener listener);`